# Convert DOC to one page PDF iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pdf, pdf-generation

Using [iOS-htmltopdf](https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf), i am able to convert DOC to PDF but i want single page PDF from doc file.

The reason is some content of one page gets into another page so only one page.

In `NDHTMLtoPDF.m` i use these 2 line of code then PDF page size becomes double

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  if (webView.isLoading) return;

  long pageHeight = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"]longLongValue];
  self.pageSize = CGSizeMake(595, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height/2);

  .........
  .........
  .........
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly convert DOC to PDF using [NDHTMLtoPDF](https://github.com/iclems/iOS-htmltopdf).

Below delegate method will be called

```
- (void)HTMLtoPDFDidSucceed:(NDHTMLtoPDF*)htmlToPDF
{
  NSLog(@"HTMLtoPDF did succeed (%@ / %@)", htmlToPDF, htmlToPDF.PDFpath);

  NSURL *pptURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlToPDF.PDFpath];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pptURL];
  [myWebView loadRequest:request];

  //now merge whole pages to one PDF
  [self MergeToOnePagePDF:pptURL];   
}
```

Now add these method:

```
-(void)MergeToOnePagePDF:(NSURL *)pdfURL
{
  CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfURL);

  int pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
  CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);
  CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pageRef, kCGPDFMediaBox);
  float pageHeight = pageRect.size.height;
  pageRect.size.height = pageRect.size.height * pageCount;

  NSMutableData* pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  CGDataConsumerRef pdfConsumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)pdfData);
  CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreate(pdfConsumer, &pageRect, NULL);

  CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0, pageRect.size.height);
  for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) 
  {
    pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0, -pageHeight);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContext, pageRef);
  }
  CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
  CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);

  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *pdfFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"destination.pdf"];

  [pdfData writeToFile: pdfFile atomically: NO];
 }
```

**EDIT** : Merging pages into one page PDF credit goes to `@iPDFDev`

Answer (score -1):

I have three options for you probably you might get your answer in any one of them.

1)check this link.[MonkeyBread](http://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/Freeware/CombinePDFs.shtml.)

2) With Pdflab you can split, combine, reorganize Pdf's.

3) All you have to do is open the doc file in preview, apple + c copies the page that you are on, apple + n., apple + v and you have the single page pdf.

I hope these help you to some extent.